# Как создать текстовый файл через форму, поместить в него информацию и поместить содержимое файла на страницу?

Tags: php

Помогите, если можете. Нужно вывести содержимое текстового файла на страницу. Важный момент! Файл должен создаваться исключительно через форму. В него должен помещаться заготовленный текст(содержимое переменной $str) и в конце выводиться на страницу. Самому опыта не хватает.

````
error_reporting(-1);

if(!empty($_POST['new_file'])) {
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
    
    $str = 'Привет, я новый файл!';
    
    file_put_contents($_POST['new_file'].'.txt', $str);

}

?>```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form method="post" action="?" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin: 20px">
        <input type="text" name="new_file" placeholder="new file" style="margin-bottom: 10px"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>


</body>
</html>
````

Comment: ну так считай обратно file_get_contents() и выведи на страницу

Comment: Я прописывал, но безрезультатно. Что-то делаю не так. Можете написать как должно быть?

Comment: header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}"); перенесите вниз после строчки file_put_contents($_POST['new_file'].'.txt', $str);

Comment: Всем спасибо, разобрался.